# Lower bound on numbers in "extension" to Lagrange four square theorem

Tags: number-theory

Can we find a representation of positive integers $n$ as the sum of six (or more, if you wish) squares in such a way that there is a (non-trivial) lower bound for the smallest square, in terms of $n$? You can assume $n$ is sufficiently large. To be precise, is there a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ that is (not strictly) increasing and unbounded such that every sufficiently large positive integer $n$ can be written in the form $a_1^2+\dots+a_6^2$ with $\min(a_1,...,a_6) \geq f(n)$?

Comment: No, since of course you can always find a solution with $a_6 = 0$.

Comment: @KCd Well of course I mean whether we can choose $a_1,...,a_6$ such that they are all greater than this bound. There is quite a bit of freedom here, we know we only need four squares. I shall rephrase the question a little though.

Comment: Then I think the order of quantification in the "to be precise" part is backwards in in its current form. Ask for existence of $f$ such that for each $n$ there is a sum of squares representation etc., not for a sum of squares representation such that there is a function etc.

Comment: @KCd thank you, edited

Comment: Introduce the function *first*. Now I have edited the question. Is the change consistent with what you were trying to ask? By the way, the "unbounded" property follows from the "increasing" property since the values of the function are in $\mathbf N$.

Comment: @KCd yes it is. I understood what you were saying, but the two formulations are equivalent... And it does not follow it is unbounded, I did not say it is strictly increasing (which would wreck it).

Comment: Thank you giving me a chance to correct the writing of Shakespeare. Never thought I would be able to do that. :)